# How can I replicate a HLM model in R using these equations?

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects, multilevel-analysis

I'd like to replicate a Multilevel Model (MLM) using R with the below equations.

#### Level 1:

Y = Betaoj + Beta1j*X1 + Beta2j*X2 + Beta3j*(X1*X2) + Beta4j(X3) + rij

#### Level 2:

- Beta0j = g00 + g01 (Sector) + u0j
- Beta1j = g10 + g11 (Sector) + u1j
- Beta2j = g20 + g21 (Sector) + u2j
- Beta3j = g30 + g31 (Sector) + u3j
- Beta4j = g40

Both X1 & X3 are dummy variables.

Here is my R code:

```
model=lmer(Y ~ 1 + X1 + X2 + X1*X2 + X3 + (X1|Sector), data=df, REML=FALSE)
summary (model)
```

It does not return the expected result. How can I fix the code?